# How to install packages/modules in IronPython

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, ironpython, python.net

I am new to IronPython. Thanks for you help and patience.

I installed IronPython 2.7 from http://ironpython.net/ in Visual Studio 2015.
I also installed Python 2.7.6 and anaconda.

I tried the following solution and it didn't work.  [Installing Python Packages - IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433684/installing-python-packages-ironpython)

I am wondering can IronPython use the modules installed by anaconda directly?

The packages I tried to install are numpy,scipy,pandas,sklearn. I saw a document in 2012 pointed out that sklearn is not supported in IronPython. Is it still the case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

depend on IronPython official website http://ironpython.net/blog/2014/12/07/pip-in-ironpython-275.html

you can follow the following steps

**Step1**

add path of ironPython installation to system path

**Step2**

run cmd as administrator and type the following command

```
ipy -X:Frames -m ensurepip
```

now you can install everything is done, you can simply add any package by following command

```
ipy -X:Frames -m pip install Package
```

Comment: This fails when I try doing this in IronPython 3.4.  Works once I installed 2.7 though.