# ERROR "No module named pandas" - trying to use machine learning(python) in ASP.NET c#

Tags: python, c#, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

````
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using IronPython.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var var1 = 0;
                var var2 = 0;
                ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
                var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
                searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\humay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310");
                engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\humay\Downloads\python.py", scope);
                dynamic testFunction = scope.GetVariable("test_func");
                var result = testFunction(var1, var2);
            }
        }
    }```

**Python**
````

````
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

def test_func(var1, var2):
    dataset = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
    X = dataset.drop(columns=['Species'])
    y = dataset['Species']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size =0.2)

    sc = StandardScaler()
    X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test = sc.fit_transform(X_test)

    classifier = GaussianNB()
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)

    print(y_pred)

# cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
# ac = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)```
````

When I run the c# code, I get the error :"No module named pandas". I have ran "pip install pandas" and its still not working. I am trying to write bayesian classifier python code and run it in my project in asp.net

Comment: It's not uncommon to have multiple Python installations.  You should run `python -m pip install pandas`, so you get the same interpreter.

Comment: Try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18433915/17242583

Answer (score 1):

You may be inside a virtual environment.
To check, try running:
`which pip`
The response will vary depending on your OS.

```
/Users/.../venv/bin/pip
```

If the response contains `venv` then use the full path as `pip` i.e.

```
/Users/.../venv/bin/pip install pandas
```